# Better way of writing this onClick event

Tags: javascript

I'm setting two text box values using an onclick event. I have used `javascript:` twice, I think this can be written in a shorter way. How do I write the onclick in a short or better way?

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('category').value='Furniture'; javascript:document.getElementById('tick').value='';">Furniture Option</button>
```

OR

```
<button type="button" onclick="shortened();">Furniture Option</button>

function shortened(){
    javascript:document.getElementById('category').value='Furniture'; 
    javascript:document.getElementById('tick').value='';
}
```

Comment: Give `ID` to the button and attach the listener using JavaScript. Don't add JavaScript code in HTML :)

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu: thanks. Can you show how to do a listener in js?

Comment: @Beki Take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: You don't need to add "javascript:" before every line of js

Comment: @Beki You can also use the script tags and add the code in your html if this is the only thing thats done.

Comment: @Beki Added the answer :) Update the business logic part. And read about [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: I see everyone's answer is giving an id and adding eventListener from js, but can any of you explain why and how is is better then adding onClick attribute from html?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin I can say one main advantage, it avoids pollution of global scope. Attaching click listener in HTML should have the function in global scope.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Its just considered  as a better coding practice. Both of them gets the job done. Check out this stackoverflow question for more details [event listener vs html onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give ID to the button and attach the listener using JavaScript. Don't add JavaScript code in HTML :)

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  // Business Logic
  alert('Clicked');
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: @Beki It means the button (the function) will process click events before passing it to parent nodes (if they are also listening). The default is `false` if you don't specify it.

Comment: That indicates the event phase. Capture phase or Bubbling phase. http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 1):

Separating Javascript from HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="furniture-button">Furniture Option</button>

<script>
    function shortened() {
        document.getElementById('category').value='Furniture'; 
        document.getElementById('tick').value='';
    }
    var furniture_button = document.getElementById("furniture-button");
    furniture_button.addEventListener("click", shortened);
    // or, the deprecated way:
    // furniture_button.onClick = shortened;
</script>
```